# How to get RUNNING TOTAL for DATES- ORDER dates in ASC RANK

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, inner-join, cumulative-sum

Imagine you have a members with distinct member_ids and dates of service
you now need to order the dates of service in ascending order and return the order of these dates in another column (date_count). the final result will look like this:

```
memberid    name       date                 date_count
122         matt       2/8/12               1
122         matt       3/9/13               2
122         matt       5/2/14               3
120         luke       11/15/11             1
120         luke       12/28/14             2
100         john       1/12/10              1
100         john       3/2/12               2
100         john       5/30/12              3
150         ore        5/8/14               1
150         ore        9/9/14               2
```

here is the query that works but does not return the date_count in ranking (1,2,3) order. This instead returns the same number for date_count, not sure why the num

```
memberid    name     date_count

122         matt     3
122         matt     3
122         matt     3
120         luke     5
120         luke     5
120         luke     5
100         john     6
100         john     6
150         ore      2
150         ore      2




SELECT A.MEMBERID, A.NAME,A.DATE, COUNT(B.DATE) AS DATE_COUNT FROM #WCV_COUNTS A
             INNER JOIN #WCV_COUNTS B
             ON A.MEMBERID <= B.MEMBERID
             AND A.MEMBERID= B.MEMBERID
             GROUP BY A.MEMBERID, A.NAME, A.DATE
             ORDER BY A.MEMBERID
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT   memberid, name, date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid ORDER BY date) AS date_count
FROM     #WCV_COUNTS
ORDER BY memberid, date
```

Comment: Hi Vishal, this returns the error 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name'... Im using SQL Server 2008...

Comment: That's weird...please check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx